# How can I merge arrays that are on the same key javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I merge these two objects in javascript?

```
h1 = {12: [{actor: 'wayne'}, {actor: 'bill'}], 13: [{actor: 'james'}]}
h2 = {13: [{actor: 'mark'}]}
```

to get:

```
result = {12: [{actor: 'wayne'}, {actor: 'bill'}], 13: [{actor: 'james'}, {actor: 'mark'}]}
```

Basically I want to concat the arrays, based on the keys of the objects.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to do the dirty work yourself. Not even `jQuery.extend` anticipates this use-case. _Maybe_ Underscore will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do that :

```
for (var k in h2) {
   h1[k]=(h1[k]||[]).concat(h2[k]);
}
```

The resulting object would be h1.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/n7j5G/) (open the console)

If you want to left h1 unchanged, do this :

```
h3 = {};
for (var k in h1) h3[k]=h1[k].slice();
for (var k in h2) h3[k]=(h3[k]||[]).concat(h2[k]);
```

Comment: I would think `concat` needed shimming but no... :-)

Comment: Shim = [compatibility layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_layer). Very popular means of adding ES5 support (read: lots of functionality) to ES3 browsers (read: IE8)

Comment: @JanDvorak OK. Got It. But concat is one of those very old standard functions. I guess we don't have much in mind because it's rarely useful.

Comment: In the second version, you could also sacrifice a small amount of performance(?) for symmetry and write the first loop as `for (var k in h1) h3[k]=(h3[k]||[]).concat(h1[k]);`

Comment: I don't really remember what is "very old standard" and what is "shiny new that should have been very old standard" when it comes to cross-browser javascript.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen at this point i think it's beneficial to downright support varargs and write an extra loop.

Comment: Yes, but we should know where to stop : it's too easy to build 3 lines generic property merging functions when we only need the two lines code only once ;)